# Create Range expression to use in Union() method

Tags: excel, vba, range, union

I want to create a range expression to use within `Union()` method.

I have this code so far:

```
Sub RangeExpresion()
Dim str As String, s

str = "2,10"
s = Split(str, ",")

' (1) If I do this it works. It selects rows 2 and 10
Union(Rows("" & s(0) & ""), Rows("" & s(1) & "")).Select

' (2) If I do this doesn't work. The expression is not correct. I get error
h = "Rows("" & s(0) & ""), Rows("" & s(1) & "")"
Union(h).Select

End Sub
```

As you can see, in first `Union()` command I use inside the expression `Rows("" & s(0) & ""), Rows("" & s(1) & "")` and is accepted and rows 2 and 10 are selected.

In second `Union()` I first try to store in a variable the same expression that works above, but this time I get error

> argument not optional

How would be the way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You already seem to have working code using syntax (1)? NB: Easier is using `Union(Rows(s(0)), Rows(s(1)))`

Comment: @GerCas Just in case `.Select` was not just for testing purpose you might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: @jkpieterse Thanks for the answer. The thing for I want to create an expression is because I obtain `str` from a previous process and in this case it has 2 rows but is variable, `str` could be for example `2,10,14,17,35` in that case would be `Union(Row(s(0),..., Rows(s(4)))`. How to make this dynamic if we have several rows?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks. Actually I put select for testing purposes hehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to build the unified range dynamically using a loop over the s array:

```
Sub RangeExpresion()
    Dim str As String
    Dim s As String
    Dim lItem As Long
    Dim rUnifiedRange As Range
    str = "2,10"
    s = Split(str, ",")
    For lItem = LBound(s) To UBound(s)
        If rUnifiedRange Is Nothing Then
            Set rUnifiedRange = Rows(s(lItem))
        Else
            Set rUnifiedRange = Union(rUnifiedRange, Rows(s(lItem)))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your help. That solves my question.

Answer (score 3):

Union requires two Range objects as a minimum, not one string.

Your first attempt generates these as Rows is not encapsulated as string literal. Your second doesn't, so one string is passed, not two ranges.

[Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union)

Returns the union of two or more ranges.

Syntax
expression.

Union ( *Arg1* , *Arg2* , *Arg3* , *Arg4* , *Arg5* , *Arg6* , *Arg7* , *Arg8* , *Arg9* , *Arg10* , *Arg11* , *Arg12* , *Arg13* , *Arg14* , *Arg15* , *Arg16* , *Arg17* , *Arg18* , *Arg19* , *Arg20* , *Arg21* , *Arg22* , *Arg23* , *Arg24* , *Arg25* , *Arg26* , *Arg27* , *Arg28* , *Arg29* , *Arg30* )

Parameters

```
Name    Required/Optional   Data type   Description
Arg1    Required            Range       At least two Range objects must be specified.
Arg2    Required            Range       At least two Range objects must be specified.
Arg3    Optional            Variant     A range.
```

---

Requested example:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub RangeExpresion()
    Dim str As String, s, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    str = "2,10"
    s = Split(str, ",")
    Set rng1 = rows("" & s(0) & "")
    Set rng2 = rows("" & s(1) & "")

    Union(rng1, rng2).Select '<==Testing only. You should avoid .Select
End Sub
```

Though jkpieterse's comment of a better way is true. `Union(Rows(s(0)), Rows(s(1)))`

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes, I see the syntax, but then how can I do what I asking? How to pass a variable within `Union ()`. And why the negative vote to my question?

Comment: I didn't downvote. I prefer to give comments on how to improve a question, or vote to close, over downvoting. But I assure you, it happens to all of us.

Comment: create two range variables and pass those in.

Comment: Then somebody unknown voted negative and I don't know why? I only asking for help doing a question.

Comment: May you share an example of a range variable please.

Comment: _Then somebody unknown voted negative and I don't know why?_ Yes. Unless they are thoughtful enough to leave a comment. Example given.

Comment: thanks for the example. The issue I have is how to do if I have several rows in variable `str`, let's say 5 or 10? Since `str` is obtained from a previous process.

Comment: In the way you have Union(Rows(s(0)), Rows(s(1))) , where s is generated from split on str